# add taxonomy as one of menu items

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus

I have created a custom `Taxonomy` called Documents and I want to show it as one of menu items, I am only able to choose from its posts. How shall I do that?

As below picture I am not able to choose Documents itself as a menu item...

[image]

Comment: What should that menu item will take us - to a Taxonomy archive, or to a Post of that taxonomy. Please [edit] your question, place the code your are working with, and elaborate with your context to get a good answer.

Comment: It should open posts of that taxonomy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to find a way to do exactly what I wanted. Though adding **Custom Taxonomy** or **Custom Post Type** can easily be added, while having its **Template** file, as following:

Appearance> Menus > selecting Links widget > putting link of custom post type or taxonomy `http://yourdomain.com/your-custom-post-or-taxonomy`

But also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22602901/3203890) help you to have a widget for your custom post type and taxonomy to select from them. The code there is for custom post type, but after working it around, it is now working for me as I had many custom post types and taxonomies.

Answer (score 0):

when registering the taxonomy you should use this parameter `'show_in_nav_menus' => true`, in order to use the terms of the taxonomy in the menu generator of WP.

For example:

```
register_taxonomy(
  'videoCategories',
  array('video'),
  array(  'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Video Categories',
      'singluar_name' => 'Video Category'
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'videos', 'with_front' => true)
  )
);
```

Comment: it still doesn't show it as top level menu, just show categories under that. Even 'show_in_menu' parameter doesn't show it.

Comment: would be better if you provide some screenshot of what you are trying to do

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Why not using this template tag to show all the terms? `wp_list_categories( $args );` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Comment: this does not answer the question, this will allow to add the taxonomy terms to the menu, but not its archive